# htmlspecialchars protection isn't working

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars

I made a function to print all the comments from a id-page. But I want to protect my site from being hacked with htmlspecialchars. So I put them arround my post that will be printed. The problem is that it isn't working? I can do whatever I want with the <>-signs.

**CODE FUNCTION**

```
public function GetAllComments($id)
            {
                    $db = new Db();

                $select = "SELECT * FROM tblcomments WHERE bug_id =" . $id . " ORDER BY comment_id DESC";
                $result = $db->conn->query($select);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {

                    echo "<li class='description'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["comment_text"]) . "</li>";
                    echo "<li class='user'>" . $row['name']  . "</li>";

                }
            }
```

**CODE PRINTING**

> if(isset($bugs)){
>       foreach ($bugs as $bug) {
>
> echo "
>
> " .
>   $bug['bug_title'] . "" .
>   $bug['bug_status'] .  "From:
>   " . $bug['name'] . "      
>  To: " . 
>   $bug['bug_to'] . " 
> Project: " .
>   $bug['project_title'] .  "";
>                         }
>                     }

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you want to save from you should use htmlspecialchars like this

```
htmlspecialchars(trim($variable), ENT_QUOTES);
```